# android application runs in AVD but stoppes in real device

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I have created a very simple android app using visual studio (xamarin for visual studio) and have changed nothing I mean the codes are as the same as default when you create an android app.

```
[Activity(Label = "App2", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
    }
}
```

When I run it, android virtual device starts and application runs normally without error but when I copy .apk file from the bin folder of my solution to my real phone it installs fine but when I want to run it it gives the "unfortunately App1 has stopped error.

I copy the "App2.App2-Signed.apk" to my phone.

and also the "Export Android Package" option in build menu of visual studio is disabled.

what is the reason?
I used to create android apps with eclipse and never got this error.

note that I don't change anything in application, The application structure and codes and etc are all the default generated by xamarin's own template.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to plug your android device into your computer? You make have to enable your phone to work with your android app.
Here is a link with more information about connecting a real android phone to an android application: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

Comment: Thank you but it is not related to google or android issues. it is a xamarin bug I think.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just pick the APK from your bin folder and make it run on your phone. You have to follow the complete process of signing and publishing the app to get the Adhoc build.

You can start here:
[Preparing an Application for Release](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/)